# React Styled-Components onClick not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, onclick, components, styled-components

I am trying to run onClick on a React component that is created from a styled-component, but it does not work without a work-around.

Style 1:

```
const GenericStyledDeleteButton = styled.button`
    height: 30px;

    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    color: green;

    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;

    &:hover {
        color: red;
    }
`;
```

Component:

```
const DeleteButton = ({className}) => (
  <GenericStyledDeleteButton className={className}
    Delete
  </GenericStyledDeleteButton>
);

Style 3:
const StyledDeleteButton = styled(DeleteButton)`
   margin-left: auto;
   margin-right: 25px; 
`;
```

I’ve created a generic styled component, then created a React native component with some text, and then added some further styling onto the generic styled component.
I am trying to perform the following:

```
<StyledDeleteButton onClick={() => DeleteItem(item._id)} />
```

I have tried both onClick and onClick but they don’t work. However, it works when I add the following:

```
const DeleteButton = ({ className, onClick }) => (
  <GenericStyledDeleteButton className={className} onClick={onClick}>
    Delete
  </GenericStyledDeleteButton>
);
```

The onClick work on other styled-components I have, but not this one.
So my question is, how do I call onClick directly on StyledDeleteButton without changing the DeleteButton component?

To use onClick directly in the styled-component without implementing a work-around.

Answer (score 1):

```
const DeleteButton = ({ className, onClick }) => (
  <GenericStyledDeleteButton className={className} onClick={onClick}>
    Delete
  </GenericStyledDeleteButton>
);
```

It is not a work-around. This is how it should work. If the `DeleteButton` does not accept `onClick`, you can not pass it. Props are passed from parent to children.

`StyledDeleteButton` passes `onClick` to `DeleteButton`. If the `DeleteButton` does not have `onClick`, it can not pass it to its children.

This is the natural way. If you do not want to change `DeleteButton`, you can make a work-around with context provider, but you have to change how `GenericStyledDeleteButton` receives `onClick`. It is not that good as adding an onClick prop to it.